# "Немыслим" - слитно или раздельно?

Tags: грамматика, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

"Без них немыслим ни один акт" или "Без них не мыслим ни один акт"?

Answer (score 1):

Частица НЕ с краткими прилагательными пишется так же, как с полными. Слово **немыслимый** пишется слитно и имеет значение "такой, который трудно или невозможно себе представить; невероятный, невозможный". Для примера приведу цитату из Национального корпуса русского языка: Без такого образования в обществе не может быть нормального интеллектуального развития; вместе с тем гуманитарное образование **немыслимо** без гуманитарной науки. (В. М. Живов, «Наука выживания и выживание науки» // «Новое литературное обозрение», 2005 г.)

В вашем случае нужно писать слитно: *Без них немыслим ни один акт*.